# Nested CASE statement in SQL using multiple variables

Tags: sql, nested, case

I am trying to create a nested CASE statement using multiple criteria.

The gist is if the duration is under 42 days and the the pathway ID is 'FLS then calculate the duration minus 56 days and show the output in ranges. If it's not 'FLS' then do the same but without - 56 days. Any cues to simplify and get it to work would be appreciated.

```
CASE
    WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY,[EVENTS].REQUEST_DATE, GETDATE()) <=42 AND [EVENTS].PATHWAY_ID = 'FLS' THEN
    CASE 
        WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, [EVENTS].REQUEST_DATE, GETDATE()) - 56 BETWEEN 1 AND 7 THEN 1 
        WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, [EVENTS].REQUEST_DATE, GETDATE()) - 56 BETWEEN 8 AND 14 THEN 2 
        WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, [EVENTS].REQUEST_DATE, GETDATE()) - 56 BETWEEN 15 AND 21 THEN 3
        WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, [EVENTS].REQUEST_DATE, GETDATE()) - 56 BETWEEN 22 AND 28 THEN 4      
        WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, [EVENTS].REQUEST_DATE, GETDATE()) - 56 BETWEEN 29 AND 35 THEN 5
        WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, [EVENTS].REQUEST_DATE, GETDATE()) - 56 BETWEEN 36 AND 42 THEN 6


    WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY,[EVENTS].REQUEST_DATE, GETDATE()) <=42 AND [EVENTS].PATHWAY_ID <> 'FLS' THEN
    CASE 
        WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, [EVENTS].REQUEST_DATE, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 1 AND 7 THEN 1 
        WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, [EVENTS].REQUEST_DATE, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 8 AND 14 THEN 2 
        WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, [EVENTS].REQUEST_DATE, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 15 AND 21 THEN 3
        WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, [EVENTS].REQUEST_DATE, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 22 AND 28 THEN 4       
        WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, [EVENTS].REQUEST_DATE, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 29 AND 35 THEN 5
        WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, [EVENTS].REQUEST_DATE, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 36 AND 42 THEN 6
   END
ELSE NULL
END AS TOTAL_6_WEEK_WAITS
```

Comment: `(DATEDIFF(DAY, [EVENTS].REQUEST_DATE, GETDATE())-1)/7+1` gives you the case value directly (not tested, make sure to use integer division)

Comment: if a value is less than 42, that value minus 56 doesn't seem like it's every going to be between 1 and 42?

Comment: Assuming this is sql server calculate your duration subtract value using `cross apply(values())`

Comment: FLS is a service where the numbers can become minus. The main issue is I'm getting this error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: Taking a negative number and subtracting 56 makes it even more negative. Are you sure you don't mean +56?

Comment: *The main issue is I'm getting this error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'* - you don't seem to have asked a question about this

Comment: so does PATHWAY_ID  even matter, the second select is the same

Comment: Explainer: I'm trying to range the waiting durations within a 6 week range (<=42) for those who are FLS, I minus 8 weeks (-56) due to the nature of the service these can become minus numbers. For all other pathways, calculate the duration's range as per normal.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the logic of your query would get you the right outputs, a way to simplify it is by checking two conditions top down:

- if your `DATEDIFF` output is less than 42
- if your `PATHWAY_ID` has the "*FLS*" value (or not)

These two conditions may correspond to two specific `CASE` statements:

- the nested one, which will subtract 56 from your `DATEDIFF` output, iff the condition of `PATHWAY_ID = 'FLS'` is satisfied (otherwise leave the `DATEDIFF` output unchanged)
- the outer one, which will divide by 7 and add 1 to get your values in range, iff the condition of `DATEDIFF(...) <= 42` is satisfied (otherwise will automatically assign `NULL`)

Here's how it should look like:

```
CASE WHEN day <= 42 
     THEN CASE WHEN PATHWAY_ID = 'FLS' 
               THEN day - 56
               ELSE day 
          END / 7 + 1 
END AS TOTAL_6_WEEKS_WAITS
```

whereas the value of the field "*day*" really corresponds (and should be replaced in your query) to `DATEDIFF(DAY,[EVENTS].REQUEST_DATE, GETDATE())`.

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ccc1e8dd677549520f29979fa7be2b45).

**Note**: I'm assuming that your DBMS is SQL Server.